# Mark PLSQL procedure/function as deprecated

Tags: oracle, plsql

Some programming tools like C# or Java can mark procedures/functions as deprecated. But Oracle PLSQL is no built in functionality for this. I wonder there is another way to support this feature.

I want them to show like "The PL/SQL compiler warnings about any PL/SQL code being compiled.".

```
96/43    PLW-06005: inlining of call of procedure 'TEST' was done
```

Comment: I'm not familiar neither with C# nor Java. Could you please clarify what do you expect to happen when a PL/SQL subroutine is marked deprecated.

Comment: Have you encountered with this oracle forum thread? https://community.oracle.com/thread/2342126

Comment: @user272735 added more details to the question.

Comment: @ozy yes i know it, thanks for remember it, i am exploring the alternatives.

Comment: This might be a good idea for another pragma: "pragma deprecated proc_name [msg]". The optional message could be something like "Use alt_proc_name instead."

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Post it on [Oracle Database Ideas](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/database-ideas).

Comment: I can't create new ideas "You are not authorized to create or update this content". I "love" Oracle Community sites :(

Comment: Oracle has added support for this in Release 12.2.  I've added an answer with details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Oracle release 12.2, there is a new `pragma` for this:

```
pragma deprecate ( deprecated_thing, 'Message to other developers' );
```

... where `deprecated_thing` is any PL/SQL identifier. The following things can be deprecated:

- Subprograms
- Packages
- Variables
- Constants
- Types
- Subtypes
- Exceptions
- Cursors

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE old_package AS
PRAGMA DEPRECATE(old_package , ’Package old_package has been deprecated in favor of new_package’);
    PROCEDURE p1;
    PROCEDURE p2;
END old_package;
```

Anyone trying to compile something that uses whatever you've deprecated will receive a PL/SQL warning in the range of PLW-6019 to PLW-6022.

You can enable these warnings as follows, so that you will see them when you try to compile code:

```
alter session set plsql_warnings = 'enable:(6019,6020,6021,6022)';
```

Alternatively, you can set your session to treat these warnings as errors:

```
alter session set plsql_warnings = 'error:6020';
```

Or, you can set the object itself to make anyone using it to get an error:

```
alter package <package with deprecated stuff> compile plsql_warnings = 'error:6020' reuse settings;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a supported function of Oracle and the PL/SQL language. You would have to develop a sort of framework that would check variables at the beginning of execution to determine if the code was depreciated however that would all have to be manually handled by development team. **This simply is not a feature yet included by Oracle.**

Answer (score 1):

We have a custom solution based on [PL/SQL Source Code Control inside the database – After Compile trigger for automatic archiving](https://technology.amis.nl/2005/10/12/plsql-source-code-control-inside-the-database-after-compile-trigger-for-automatic-archiving/).

> Whenever we compile – create or replace – a PL/SQL object, the CREATE DDL event is fired and we can intercept that event with our own trigger. At that point we have various pieces of information that we can use to insert a new record into the PLSQL_ARCHIVE table.

The overall process is as follows

- The trigger collects information about the compiled object (keywords
  in comments). One of these keywords is `deprecated` in header method 
  (default: `false`).
- Then the trigger analyzes the methods used and checks if is deprecated. If 
  the method is obsolete then it stores in our `warning_table`.
- To display the warning (the tricky part) we rewrite the view 
  `USER_ERRORS` merging with our `warning_table`.

Now we have a useful message when the object is compiled:

`OPLW-00001: The method SomeDeprecatedMethod is deprecated`

Note: Sorry, i can not share source code because is an internal development.

Answer (score -1):

```
dbms_output.put_line('This function is deprecated');
```

Comment: dbms_output is not executed when code being compiled

Comment: dbms_output.put_line is "visible" only when the method is executed. The question is "_compiler warnings about any PL/SQL code being compile_".

Comment: Yes sure, all clear. DDL Trigger would be a way. Cheers ;)