# Is there a way to mark SQL Server objects as deprecated?

Tags: sql-server, intellisense, deprecated

I'd like to mark some SQL Server tables, columns, stored procedures and functions as deprecated. Something like pragma in Oracle [Mark PLSQL procedure/function as deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760629/mark-plsql-procedure-function-as-deprecated)

I can't remove them right away because it would break a lot of things in our legacy system. Because there are a lot of objects with similar or misleading names, it's common for a member of the team to utilize them inadvertedly. If existed something that would indicate visually that an object should not be used anymore, it would be perfect!

I'm looking for something like the IDE intellisense shows deprecation for common programming languages like Java as in this image:

[image]

Comment: You could use an [extended property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: @Larnu, can I get any visual reference of an object marked with an extended property in a SQL Client?

Comment: What do you mean by a "visual reference"?

Comment: Something that could show the names in another color like light grey, or even an strikethrough style. Anything that could point to a programmer "hey, don't use that anymore! Let's try to get rid of that ASAP"

Comment: I'm gonna edit the question with an example image in programming

Comment: No, there is nothing native like that in SSMS. If you want to make it visual, you'd need to create your own feature to do so.

Comment: @Larnu I was hoping there could be another SQL Client, or extensions, or any standard on how to declare something in SQL is deprecated... :(

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps use RAISERROR to print a warning message that a procedure is deprecated.

```
RAISERROR('This procedure is deprecated.', 1, 0);
```

If you use a low severity for the error then it shouldn't affect code execution, however it would display a message to other developers who are calling the procedure.

Comment: Thanks @dyoung, but I was searching for a way to show a database object is deprecated in design time instead of runtime. Something that could aid us visually like the autocomplete example I posted.